# How to use the date_trunc function for biweekly grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I need to use the date_trunc function to group biweekly.

The function, however, only have the options **day**, **week** and **month**. Does anyone know how to do it?

Above the code I have for week:

```
(date_trunc('week', CAST((CAST("Account"."createdAt" AS timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 day') AS timestamp)) - INTERVAL '1 day')
```

Comment: Could you, please, edit your question with table formed sample of data that you have in and you want out?

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bdb6e7a849459c29c17d38c3af7854af)

```
SELECT
    date_part('week', value)::int / 2,
    array_agg(value)
FROM
    mydates
GROUP BY 1
```

You can take the week number and integer divide it by `2`. For week 20: `20 / 2 == 10`; for week 21: `21 / 2 == 10` as well. With this you can group every two weeks.

---

Of course, if there are several years in your table, you need to take the `year` part in account too...

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6a024c788f3967ccd696eb340e9c7bab)

```
SELECT
    date_part('year', value) as year,
    date_part('week', value)::int / 2,
    array_agg(value)
FROM
    mydates
GROUP BY 1,2
```